# Convert a Pointer to TBytes

Tags: delphi

I have this code:

```
procedure  MyFunct(const aBin; aBinSize : Cardinal);
var bytes: Tbytes;
begin
  bytes := Tbytes(@aBin);
  for var I := 0 to aBinSize - 1 do
    writeln(bytes[i]);
end;      

var Memory: Pointer
...init the memory...
MyFunct(Memory^, sizeOfMemory);
```

this was working very well for several years with `{$R-}` (range check off). however today I decide to deactivate `{$R-}` and now the code below crash with range check error and when yes that normal because I do `length(bytes)` it's often equal to 0.

So I can reactivate the `{$R-}` but now I think it's a fundamental mistake because as far as I understand the length of a Tbyte is store at bytes[-32bit] and most important the reference count of the Tbytes is store at bytes[-64bit]. So now I m affraid that the code before was simply writen the reference count in bytes[-64bit] and destroying my memory (maybe not not sure).

so is it a good practice to do

```
bytes := Tbytes(@aBin);
```

If not why the compiler authorize it ? How without a Tbytes I can navigate through each byte of my memory (ie how to access myMemory[x])

Comment: The compiler doesn't "authorize" it. Your hard cast basically tells the compiler to shut up, to ignore the type mismatch, and that you know better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't type-cast an arbitrary pointer to a `TBytes` like you are, they are completely different things.  The code will fail if the memory being pointed at is not a valid dynamic array to begin with.  Your code has been faulty for years, and you are just lucky it did anything at all.

The function needs to look more like this instead when using `TBytes` as you are:

```pascal
procedure MyFunct(const aBin; aBinSize : Cardinal);
var bytes: TBytes;
begin
  SetLength(bytes, aBinSize);
  Move(aBin, bytes[0], aBinSize);
  for var I := 0 to aBinSize - 1 do
    WriteLn(bytes[i]);
end;
```

Otherwise, a simpler approach (which is likely what you were attempting to do) would be more like this instead:

```pascal
procedure MyFunct(const aBin; aBinSize : Cardinal);
var bytes: PByte;
begin
  bytes := PByte(@aBin);
  for var I := 0 to aBinSize - 1 do
    WriteLn(bytes[i]);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy! Conclusion: never set {$R-} in you code (in debug) else you will never detect stuff like this :(

Comment: Which is why its unbelievable that default debug config has it turned off! See https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16751